# VBA loop to change cell value (pos/neg) and font color based on adjacent cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very new to VBA and I'm having trouble understanding how to accomplish 2 tasks in one loop. I greatly appreciate your help.

I have been able to change the numeric value in column 2 based on data in column 3, but I dont understand how to change the font of the negative values to red.

The size of the table changes monthly based on days in the month (if that matters). Thank you!

```
Dim AQRng As Range, Cel As Range, p_AQend As Object
Set p_AQend = Range("AQ2").End(xlDown)
Set AQRng = Range("AQ2", p_AQend)

For Each Cel In AQRng
  If Cel.Value <> 0 Then
   If Cel.Offset(0, 1).Text = "Negative" Then
    Cel.Value = Abs(Cel.Value) * -1
  ElseIf Cel.Offset(0, 1) <> "Negative" Then
    Cel.Value = Abs(Cel.Value)
  End If
 End If
Next Cel
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use the Excel conditional formatting : https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f

Comment: Also, in the your ElseIf your forget the `.text`

Comment: Fabulous! Thank you so much! Thank you also for the link and info re:Font colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rng As Range, cl As Range

    Set rng = Range("AQ2:QA" & Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row)

    For Each cl In rng
        If cl.Value <> 0 Then
            If cl.Offset(0, 1) = "Negative" Then
                cl = Abs(cl) * -1
                cl.Font.Color = vbRed
            Else
                cl = Abs(cl)
            End If
        End If
    Next cl
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm understanding this correctly.  The `Cel` that you are changing the value on (by multiplying by -1) is the `Cel` you would like to change the color on, correct?

If so,

```
For Each Cel In AQRng
    If Cel.Value <> 0 Then
        If Cel.Offset(0, 1).Text = "Negative" Then
            Cel.Value = Abs(Cel.Value) * -1
            Cel.Font.ColorIndex = 3
        ElseIf Cel.Offset(0, 1) <> "Negative" Then
            Cel.Value = Abs(Cel.Value)
        End If
    End If
Next Cel
```

I have added a line under your negative condition:

`Cel.Font.ColorIndex = 3`. The `.Font.ColorIndex` will change the color of the font to whatever you choose - `ColorIndex = 3` happens to change it to red.

Please [Read Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/colorindex-property) for more information on the various font colors you can choose using `ColorIndex`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : I added  `Cel.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)` in your negative condition

```
Dim AQRng As Range, Cel As Range, p_AQend As Object
Set p_AQend = Range("AQ2").End(xlDown)
Set AQRng = Range("AQ2", p_AQend)

For Each Cel In AQRng
  If Cel.Value <> 0 Then
   If Cel.Offset(0, 1).Text = "Negative" Then
    Cel.Value = Abs(Cel.Value) * -1
    Cel.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

  ElseIf Cel.Offset(0, 1) <> "Negative" Then
    Cel.Value = Abs(Cel.Value)
  End If
 End If
Next Cel
```

Comment: You can also use the VBA constant `vbRed` instead of the `RGB` value.

Answer (score 1):

here's a no-loop solution:

```
   With Range("AR2", cells(Rows.Count, "AR").End(xlUp))
        .Replace what:="Positive", replacement:="", lookat:=xlWhole
        With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
            .Offset(, 1).Value = .Offset(, -1).Value
            .Offset(, -1).FormulaR1C1 = "=ABS(RC[2])"
            .Value = "Positive"
        End With

        .Replace what:="Negative", replacement:="", lookat:=xlWhole
        With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
            .Offset(, 1).Value = .Offset(, -1).Value
            .Offset(, -1).FormulaR1C1 = "=-ABS(RC[2])"
            .Value = "Negative"
            .Font.Color = vbRed
        End With
        .Offset(, -1).Value = .Offset(, -1).Value
        .Offset(, 1).ClearContents
    End With
```

this supposes column AS can be written, but the code is easily changeable to use a different *helper* column

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way to change negative values to red.

```
    Columns("AQ:AQ").NumberFormat = "0.00_ ;[Red]-0.00 "
```